# Are these consistent dull joints an indication of poor solder?

Tags: soldering

Having nearly run through my stock of leaded solder I bought some leaded solder from a cheap supplier (Ebay).  Thus I think I have bought dud solder: every joint is consistently dull.  Whilst dullness is not an infallible indicator, I've never seen it like this everywhere.  Other than that the solder behaves normally: joints conduct properly, it wets fine, flows fine and has no trouble adhering.

Is this just a case of buy cheap, by twice?

Here's a comparison: right two joints are soldered with old solder; left two with new.  I seem to have used slightly too much solder on all of them.

[image]

The generic solder:

[image]

Bumping the iron temperature up---even to a nominal 400C---has no effect on the joints.

Comment: More likely a case of not hot enough.  What solder did you buy?

Comment: That's typical of lead-free solder.

Comment: @Armandas i.e. this is in fact lead-free solder?  That would explain it I guess...

Comment: Does it have flux in it? Did you use flux or apply the solder directly without external flux? Tbh this looks still acceptable, mild surface oxidation shouldn't affect anything unless there is a good reason why it would. Also, lead-free, as pointed out by Armandas, is less shiny by nature. Source: I fix electronics and solder almost daily.

Comment: It claims to have flux... I do wonder whether it's simply in deficient quantities.  I don't actually have any flux on hand to check with.  Increasing temperature @JRE doesn't help in this case (just checked again).

Comment: It is possible you are cooling it quick. Is it very cold? Or are you blowing air to cool it off?

Comment: @SKGadi neither: the room is at a pretty normal temperature, and I'm not doing anything to cool it off.

Comment: Sorry.  I somehow had the idea you were using lead-free solder.  Lead-free sometimes takes a higher temperature to get a shiny joint.  You're using what claims to be 60/40 tin/lead solder.  It ought to make shiny joints by itself.  You've got junk.  Get a better solder.

Comment: If it is genuine 60/40 tin/lead solder, it should melt completely touching an iron at 300C. If it looks like sludge at that temperature, it may well be fake. My understanding is that tin is much more expensive than lead, so they may have skimped on the tin.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy in that case it might make some decent fishing weights!  Thanks all: I bought junk; now I'll chase down a reputable source of lead solder...

Comment: Watch https://youtu.be/5Ku7I3hA3AA. Looks alot like what you are experiencing.

Comment: "It was cheap but doesn't work" How exactly is that cheap? These kind of questions are getting very tiresome - can people please just stop buying cheap crap from Ebay/Ali and then post here wondering why the cheap crap they bought is cheap crap.

Comment: @Lundin I took a risk perfectly well aware of what would probably happen, and I certainly don't blame anybody except myself.  What I wanted to know was the failure mode--it didn't look like insufficient flux; I didn't think of the alloy being incorrect.  I guess the question could have been clearer...

Comment: @2e0byo Well it's not RoHS flux, that's for sure, or it would be labelled "Sn99 Ag0.3 Cu0.7" or some such (and some RoHS logo too, likely). You'll also want it to say "no clean"/"NC" flux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Are these consistent dull joints an indication of poor solder?

Very likely. Fake 60/40 solder is a known thing coming out of China.

See for example [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8cCja0FsYUs) and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Ku7I3hA3AA).

Genuine 60/40 solder has a melting point of 188 C. With luck it can be melted with a soldering iron set at 200 C. There should be no problem tinning a soldering iron set at 300 C with 60/40 solder.

If however, the solder forms a "sludge" when brought into contact with a 300 C iron, the solder is probably "fake" 60/40.

At this writing (Feb. 2022) tin is significantly more expensive than lead -- $44,150/ton vs $2,361/ton. It is likely that fake 60/40 solder has a higher percentage of lead than the advertised 40%.

Comment: Yep, those videos are what I'm experiencing.  Amazingly enough cheap ebay solder turned out to be rubbish.  Thanks!